# Crystal Reports Cross-Tab Implementation

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I am requested to make a report base on this design, is this possible to achieved in crystal reports 2008 using cross-tab ?? or is there another way to achieved this ?
please help thank you.

[image: requested format]

Comment: This doesn't look like a cross tab, but like a regular report with the subtotal line swung over to the side.  It should be relatively easy to do.

Comment: @AnnL., can you show some example on how to achieved it ?  one of my problem is that the border line, it  should not be shown once the it is merge

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't currently have Crystal Reports, so I can't walk you through it, but I can try to answer questions.  Which border line do you mean?

Comment: @AnnL. in the Sub Total column, i want that if two rows have the same item it will merge the cell. like what happen on that example. ITEM_3, it has the same item and class so the cell merge, but they have different batchNo and quantity, and since they have the same item, in the SubTotal, it will also merge, the lower border line will be erase.

Comment: Are you able to get the cells on the left to merge successfully?  The Item and Class cells?

Comment: yes, f i used the crosstab. because it is part of the group function. so the item and class will merge its column cell if they have the same value/output, but then after quantity column, it will won't now merge the cell even if it has the same value. I already tried to check the suppress if duplicate function of subTotal column. but it didn't suppress.

Comment: is the subtotal column one that you are returning through the underlying query, or one that you calculate in the report?:

Comment: its part on the query.

Comment: Have you tried grouping on the subtotal amount as well as on the item and class?  Or would that change the position of the subtotal column?

Comment: it will still not merge because from the quantity column, it has difference value already that's why it will make separation bar. :(